# Altair stacked-chart not showing all values

Tags: python, pandas, altair, stacked-chart, streamlit

i have something strange in my opinion.
I have a dataframe with 3 columns. I created a stacked bar, but not all values are shown in my stacked-bar graphic.

This is my code:

```
#Create STACKED bar
data3 = data.groupby(['Bouwnummer', 'Omschrijving klachttype']).size().to_frame('Aantal klachten')

data3.reset_index(inplace=True)

st.dataframe(data = data3)

chart2 = alt.Chart(data3).mark_bar().encode(
x='Bouwnummer',
y='Aantal klachten',
color='Omschrijving klachttype'
).interactive()

# Show the chart2
st.altair_chart(chart2, use_container_width=True)
```

[My dataframe shown with streamlit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHvEn.png)

[Stacked bar in streamlit not showing all values of 'Bouwnummer 63'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi8m2.png)

Why are not all values of 'Bouwnummer 63' shown in the graph?

Thnx in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the bars to be stacked, you can specify this in the `stack` argument of the `y` encoding:

```python
chart2 = alt.Chart(data3).mark_bar().encode(
  x='Bouwnummer',
  y=alt.Y('Aantal klachten', stack=True),
  color='Omschrijving klachttype'
).interactive()
```

Alternatively, if you ensure that the `x` encoding is ordinal rather than quantitative, the bars will be stacked by default:

```python
chart2 = alt.Chart(data3).mark_bar().encode(
  x='Bouwnummer:O',
  y='Aantal klachten',
  color='Omschrijving klachttype'
).interactive()
```

Comment: Thnx! That did the job!
I thought column 'Bouwnummer' was ordinal. I guess not.